# Magento Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, html, navigation, iframe

**Is there a way to add**

```
<a href="#" target=_parent...
```

or

```
<base target="_blank">
```

To the links in magento navigation?

The reason I ask is because I'm not good enough with code to take the navigation from magento and add it to my phpbb forum so I want to create the illusion.

I'm currently using an iframe but I need to use a target to ensure that my iframe will link outside of the iframe and behave like a normal navigation.

I don't want to edit core files because I don't know what I'm doing.

Hope you can help,

Matthew.

Comment: You want to change magento default menu navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not right way but this can be possible by doing below steps:

1. Create a static block (Admin > CMS > Add new block).
2. While creating a category you want to use in navigation,

Select Category Display settings > Display Mode > Static block only.

Select static block you created.

Paste the below code in your static block

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e){ 
window.location = "http://www.google.co.in";
}
</script>
```